# Using Spring property placeholders with Feign jaxrs @Path

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, feign

I am trying to resolve a Spring placeholder on a Feign interface using jaxrs contract :

```
@FeignClient(value = "myClient"
    , url = "${server.url}"
    , configuration = MyFeignConf.class)
public interface MyClient {

@GET
@Path("${server.querypath}")
@Produces("application/json")
JsonNode olaTvQuery(@QueryParam("nbResults") int nbResults)

}
```

But found out that only `server.url` was resolved by SpringBoot's placeholder filling mechanism. `${server.querypath}` is not resolved and is given to `GET` as a literal value.

Anyone doing that ? Should I open a feature request ? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the annotation is mapping an URL to the method it has a certain syntax to allow for functionality like referencing path variables. For example:

```
@Path("/user/{id}")
public Response getUser(@PathParam("id") int userId) {
    // ... 
}
```

And since the `$` character is allowed to be present in an URL, Jersey(JAX-RS) is actually looking at what your wrote like `@Path("<some path that happens to contain a $>{and a path variable goes here}")` and this is where things would get ambiguous and very hard to keep track of, so spring doesn't interfere with the mapping string.